# Is blockchain necessary?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I am interested in developing a crypto-currency (who isn't), but I have no interest in the blockchain mining aspect of it. I want to program one that emits the coins when someone has performed some verified work in the real world.

So, does that still require the use of blockchain?

Comment: Printing money is illegal in a lot of countries. Careful. There's a reason Bitcoin is decentralised and therefore needs a blockchain. Look up the histories of hashcash and Liberty Dollar.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to program one that emits the coins when someone has performed
>   some verified work in the real world.

This is fiat currency. You receive some coins for performing some work for someone :) No blockchain needed

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain is simply a solution for decentralized consensus.  Think of the blockchain as a big database that contains a ledger of who owns how many coins.  The question is, who can be trusted to maintain this ledger?  If a single entity owns it, then that entity can act maliciously (steal other people's money) or be coerced/shut down by governments.  The blockchain is a solution to create a ledger where nobody is in charge, but rather operates by agreement.  The proof-of-work that miners perform make it unfeasible for any one individual to control the entire network.

If you don't have the need for decentralized consensus, then you don't need a blockchain.  It sounds like you want to be in complete control of the issuing of new currency, and therefore, a blockchain would be a wasteful solution for you.  If you don't want your currency to have any central authority, then a blockchain is a well-vetted solution.  It all depends on your intent.

Comment: I want just to add: the adversary model for blockchain is: everyone is entitled to manage a copy of the ledger, everyone claims his copy is the true one, everyone tries to cheat and tamper the ledger in his favour. The Proof-of-work addresses this model. Your model is different